# How to configure an SSL certificate only for the custom domain ( skip domains *.azurewebsites.net)

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service

I have several (4) web apps running on Azure: 3  of them require very little processing power, thus, they had been running
on a Free plan; while the other one is meant for final users which means a higher load and a needs for a custom domain and SSL certificate.

SSL certificate was correctly configured (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site/) and is working as expected.
However, we noticed all of the other sites are now importing this SSL certificate as opposed to the one offered by default by Azure (the one for *.azurewebsites.net sites);
this has caused all of our Free sites to move to the Basic tier automatically. We are the unable to set them to Free again, as an error message states Free does not support 
our custom SSL certificate for our custom domain.

Notice that our custom domain is in no way associated with any of the (3) Free sites but just the one that needs it.
Also, when going to SSL cert options in our Free sites, we cannot remove the custom SSL cert, as it states the site requires at least one of them, and custom one is the only one.
When creating a new site, this custom SSL will be automatically imported as well.

What should we do so the Free sites make use of the default *.azurewebsites.net SSL cert instead of the custom one, so we can then get back these sites to the Free plan?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: are all your sites on the same hosting plan? Hosting plan is basically a server with IIS. Most likely you'll need to move your production site to a separate hosting plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.Root cause: It maybe that use the same hosting plan for all your websites.**

As free app service plan doesn’t support custom SSL, if you want to use your user custom SSL then need to scale up to app service plan from to basic or higher.

After scaling up the App service plan, it will apply to all your websites in your app service plan.

**2. How to resolve it**

Please have a try to create another free app service plan for the 3 websites. Detail please refer to [how to create-a-new-app-service-plan](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview/#create-a-new-app-service-plan-vs-use-an-existing-plan) and [Move an app to a different App Service plan](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview/#move-an-app-to-a-different-app-service-plan).

*Note: Only valid plans (in the same resource group and geographical location) are shown.*

Answer (score 0):

With Azure websites you are basically renting an IIS instance. In order to use SSL on your website you need to switch your plan to "Basic" or higher, as you've seen. Right now I think all of your websites are in the same "webhosting" plan. This means that they are automatically scaled to the "Basic", as you are basically scaling the IIS instance, not the indiviudual website.

See it as buying a hosting plan that can host multiple web applications. If you move to basic, you end up paying for 1 basic plan that hosts all 4 sites (so not 4 billable plans, just 1).

In this case you won't end up with a higher bill (you need a basic instance for the SSL-site anyway) - the other sites are including in this same hosting plan for 'free' - sharing the resources of the basic instance).

If you want to keep the basic site and the 3 free sites separated, you should create a new webhosting plan (App service plan) on the new Azure Portal (https://portal.azure.com) and move those 3 websites there.

I would recommend letting those 3 sites use the basic plan - it won't cost you any extra.